# How to extract polygon location data (County) to a point shapefile (only has DMS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point-in-polygon, excel

I have imported an excel spreadsheet to my map and the points have fallen into certain locations. How do I add the location of the polygon that the point has landed in, to the attributes table of the point without hand jamming it all in one point at a time? For instance a table full of school locations has no county data in the table. How would I add the county to the schools attribute table?

Comment: You're looking for "point in polygon" analysis. How you find it will depend on which GIS software you're using.

Comment: Look for a Spatial Join tool.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include details of the GIS software you are using, please?

Comment: GeoRover RPF tool is what i used to import the excel spread sheet. just looking at the spread sheet i have no idea where the schools are located. But when i import the spread sheet to ArcMap with the county shapefile already in the map I can visually see where the schools land what I want to do is based on the county shape add a field to the shools attribute table and import the county the point falls with in. What programs would i need to accomplish this?

Comment: To show your appreciation to @GeoKevin I recommend that you click the green tick next to his Answer to Accept it.

Answer (score 3):

Use a **[Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000)** with the school points and county polygons loaded in ArcMap.

1. right-click the ***schools*** layer, highlight **Joins & Relates**, and click **Join**
2. choose **Join data from another layer based on spatial location**
3. the *Layer to Join* is your ***county*** layer
4. each point should be given the attributes of the polygon that **it falls inside**
5. specify an output shapefile or feature class name and click **OK**
6. add the new layer to the map and examine its attributes to see which county each school lies in

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply use "intersect" function in ArcGIS.
Simply by intersecting your polygon layer with your DMS point layer